# difference in behavior within if statements for python

Tags: python

i had two statements and my friend is claiming to me they are not the same.  i believe they are.  I was wondering if they are and if they aren't is there an example where the behavior is different.

```
if (n != p and c/n > 5.15):

if (c/n > 5.15 and n !=p):
```

Comment: Run them with `n = p = 0` and see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They could be different due to the short-circuiting behavior of `and`.  If the first operand of `and` is false, the second is not evaluated.  So if `c/n > 5.15` raises an exception (for instance if `n` is zero), the first `if` may work (that is, not raise any error) while the second causes an error.  Here is an example:

```
c = 0
n = 0
p = 0

# No error, no output because the condition was not true
>>> if (n != p and c/n > 5.15):
...     print "Okay!"

# Raises an error
>>> if (c/n > 5.15 and n !=p):
...     print "Okay!"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    if (c/n > 5.15 and n !=p):
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Comment: Just to make things clear: from a pure boolean logic POV, both expressions are indeed equals. From a Python code POV they are not.

Comment: Sure, but this is a question tagged Python on StackOverflow, not a logic question on Math SE.